# Confusion About Pointclasses

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I am doing some work learning about the Axiom of Determinacy and its consequences. This has led me to learning about the properties of the Baire space, $\omega^\omega$. I have recently come across the concept of pointclasses, given with the following definition. $\Gamma$ is a pointclass if it consists of pairs $(A,X)$, where A is a subset of the Polish space $X$. I am having trouble understanding the definition and figuring out exactly what a point class is. Are there any examples of pointclasses that would be helpful to keep in mind? Or is there an intuitive explanation of exactly what a pointclass is?

Comment: A pointclass is just a collection of sets of reals closed under Wadge reduction (or continuous inverse images), that is if $A$ is in the pointclass and $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(A)$ is also in the pointclass. It's easier to see it this way.

Comment: Does this not add a further property to the definition given in my question? It seems to me that saying the pointclass must be closed under continuous preimages takes away some of the pointclasses that could be talked about?

Comment: No because what you've defined in your post is not a pointclass. It's just a random collection of sets of reals (in the case of Baire space). A pointclass must specify a precise level of complexity and this is made precise using Wadge reductions, o/w it's just a random collection of sets.

Comment: @16278263789 I'm unaware of a text that requires that pointclasses be closed under Wadge reduction; do you have a source for that? (My own understanding was that a pointclass *was* merely a collection of subsets of Polish spaces.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard examples are:

- **The open sets**. This is the pointclass consisting of pairs $(A, X)$ where $X$ is a Polish space and $A\subseteq X$ is open.
- **The closed sets.** This is the pointclass consisting of pairs $(A, X)$ where $X$ is a Polish space and $A\subseteq X$ is closed.

Similarly, we also have:

- **The $G_\delta$ sets.**
- **The Borel sets.**
- **The analytic sets.** (That is, pairs $(A, X)$ where $X$ is a Polish space and $A\subseteq X$ is the continuous image of some Borel subset of $X$.)
- **The coanalytic sets.**

Etc.

We also have silly examples, like:

- **The set of pairs $(A, X)$ where $X$ is a Polish space and $A$ has fewer than 17 points.**
- **The set containing just $(\{\pi\},\mathbb{R})$.**

---

Basically, think of a pointclass as the set of all pointsets which are describable in some nice way. For instance, the Borel pointclass is the pointclass of all sets which have Borel codes; the open pointclass is the pointclass of all sets which are formed by taking unions of open balls; and so forth.

In descriptive set theory, you'll be interested in pointclasses that satisfy reasonable properties; for instance, being closed under continuous preimages. These closure properties are what the silly examples described above lack.

Comment: So is the pointclass essentially just a collection of subsets, $A \subseteq X$, $X$ a Polish space, where A has some specific property?

Comment: @Matt Yup, pretty much - with the caveat that the Polish space is also allowed to vary! There will be times you'll want to require some additional properties (e.g. Spector pointclasses) but a general pointclass is just a class of subsets of Polish spaces.